# bind values into modal's window

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I have a code like this
HTML

```
<div ng-controller="modalCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="modal">
        <div ng-repeat="add in addOn">
            <p>{{add.name}}</p>
            <p>{{add.description}}</p>
        </div>
    </script>
</div>
```

JS

```
var modalCtrl=function($scope){
    $scope.addOn=[
        {name:'addOne',description:'firstDescription'},
        {name:'addSecond',description:'secondDescription'}
     ]
```

my problem is that the modal doesn't display the values inside the brackets like they were not bound, for the rest everything goes ok, the ng-repeat goes well, as the modal opens or closes and anything else, is there some reasons that i don't know about binding into modal's window?
EDIT 
The $scope was allready presents in my code, i ask sorry for didn't write it in the question, but  the problem still remains.
I'm sorry if i didn't write the code exactly well, anyway my question is generic, why the html bind into the bracket seems to be not bind to the value in the javascript file?
SECOND EDIT
i have see that if i write in the html code

```
{{addOn}}
```

i can see repeated the entire addOn array, but i still don't undestand why i cannot access to the single values, any ideas?

Comment: this isn't proper form of controller, at least you should inject `$scope`

Comment: Where's the code that's setting this up as a modal window?

Comment: the code is a general code, i open the modal in another controller, but the point is, why it seems that inside the modal i cannot bind a value that's write in the modal controller?

Comment: Also - you are missing a comma between the array elements, ie.  `addOn=[{...}, {...}]`

Answer (score 0):

controller needs $scope

```
var modalCtrl=function($scope){
$scope.addOn=[
    {name:'addOne',description:'firstDescription'}
    {name:'addSecond',description:'secondDescription'}
 ]
```

See here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Also, this is probably the cleaner way of defining your controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('modalCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    // code
}]);
```

Comment: i have forget to write the injection in the question but it's allready written in my code